# can't use If - Else element exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I wrote a JS function to create a table in html and JS I want to click submit and after that the table to be created but I dont want the Submit button to create another table if clicked again 
I tried to use IF - Else statements in the function but It's not working

code:

Button:

```
 document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click",sizeGrid)
```

function

```
 function makeGrid(x,y) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById('tbl') != null)
      {
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        var body = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
        var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
        for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
           var tr = tbl.insertRow();
            for(var j = 0; j<y; j++){
              var td= tr.insertCell()
           }

        }

         body.append(tbl);
         paint()
      }

      }
```

HTML

```
    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table  id="pixelCanvas">
</table>
```

The table gets created two times after I click submit two times

Comment: You don't have an element with id `tbl`. You have a _variable_ with that name.

Comment: You are not setting id of the table when you create it

Comment: How to set an id for the table in JS
Or
How to use the variable tbl

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `tbl`'s id to `'tbl'` by `tbl.id = 'tbl'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the check on the id of the table but never assign one.

```
function makeGrid(x,y) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (document.getElementById('tbl') != null) {
    return;
  } else {
    var body = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.id = "tbl"; // Assign the id for the check
    for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){
      var tr = tbl.insertRow();
      for(var j = 0; j<y; j++){
        var td= tr.insertCell()
        }
    }
    body.append(tbl);
    paint();
  }

};
```